# How can I use scaffolding in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding

I was following an ASP.NET MVC tutorial and in the section that he used scaffolding to make controller and views, I got an error.

I searched but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

It's the error message:

[image: Scaffolding Error message]

My startup class:

[Startup configure function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkbGd.png)

.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ASP.NetCore5Tutorial\DataLayer\DataLayer.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And there is no error in the error list. The project builds successfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your .csproj file and please make sure your package matches your project version.

Comment: @Yinqiu I checked versions and that was ok. Here is the .csproj file : [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13t_i6GA79UzcB8OUNOMMPkImIvL2DlMK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share it in your case?You can edit your case and add it.

Comment: @Yinqiu  Done. I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling visual studio.

But I found out it can be solved by installing code generator package from Nuget or with package console manager using the below command:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```